Different comparison column in WHERE clause causes unexpected slowdown
(All identifiers below are anonymized.)
I have the following query in Postgres:
SELECT id, dt
FROM table1 t1
WHERE status is not null
    AND (
        (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.big_int_id = t1.big_int_id and t2.count is not null)
            AND t1.dt > NOW() - INTERVAL '15 minutes'
        ) OR
        (NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM table3 t3
                JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.another_id = t3.another_id AND
                    t2.big_int_id = t3.big_int_id
            )
            AND t1.dt BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '15 minutes' AND NOW()
        )
    )

It takes about 1 second to execute.
I then changed:
(SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.big_int_id = t1.big_int_id and t2.count is not null)

to:
(SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.text_id = t1.text_id and t2.count is not null)

Now the query takes 10 minutes + to execute. I have limited experience with SQL, and don't know why this is causing a slowdown.
The change from comparing on big_int_id (a column with big integer type) to text_id (a column with text type, but the text is of the form "XYZ-#####" where ##### represents some integral value between 1 to 1 billion) seems to result in 2 changes:

Comparing on text instead of bigint - idk how much slower that can be?

In t1, there are exactly 2 rows for each distinct t1.big_int_id, but there is exactly 1 row for each distinct  t2.text_id, and 98% of rows have t2.text_id as null (though subject to change in the future, and note that t1.text_id is never null). I think the Cartesian product created from the SELECT statement may somehow be a lot bigger?


Query plan for unmodified query:
Seq Scan on table t1  (cost=0.00..7362242.49 rows=1 width=24)
  Filter: ((status is null) AND (((NOT (SubPlan 1)) AND (dt > (now() - '00:15:00'::interval))) OR ((NOT (SubPlan 2)) AND (dt >= (now() - '00:15:0
0'::interval)) AND (dt <= now()))))
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Index Scan using idx_t2_QRID on table2 t2  (cost=0.56..80.66 rows=17 width=0)
          Index Cond: (big_int_id = t1.big_int_id)
          Filter: (count IS NOT NULL)
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..239.84 rows=2 width=0)
          ->  Index Only Scan using idx_t2_QRID on table2 q_1  (cost=0.56..22.64 rows=38 width=8)
                Index Cond: (big_int_id = t1.big_int_id)
          ->  Index Only Scan using idx_table3_qid_rt on table3 t3  (cost=0.42..5.71 rows=1 width=8)
                Index Cond: (big_int_id = q_1.big_int_id)

Query plan for modified query:
Seq Scan on table t1  (cost=0.00..2318157244.23 rows=1 width=24)
  Filter: ((status is null) AND (((NOT (SubPlan 1)) AND (dt > (now() - '00:15:00'::interval))) OR ((NOT (SubPlan 2)) AND (dt >= (now() - '00:15:0
0'::interval)) AND (dt <= now()))))
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on table2 t2  (cost=0.00..671602.70 rows=17 width=0)
          Filter: ((count IS NOT NULL) AND (text_id = t1.text_id))
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..239.84 rows=2 width=0)
          ->  Index Only Scan using idx_t2_QRID on table2 q_1  (cost=0.56..22.64 rows=38 width=8)
                Index Cond: (big_int_id = t1.big_int_id)
          ->  Index Only Scan using idx_table3_qid_rt on table3 t3  (cost=0.42..5.71 rows=1 width=8)
                Index Cond: (big_int_id = q_1.big_int_id)

Indexes for t1:
CREATE INDEX t1_text_id     ON t1 (text_id)
CREATE INDEX t1_id          ON t1 (id)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t1_pkey ON t1 (id10)

Indexes for t2:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_t2_text_id ON t2 (text_id)
CREATE INDEX idx_t2_QRID           ON t2 (big_int_id, id5)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t2_pkey        ON t2 (id5)

Indexes for t3:
CREATE INDEX idx_table3_qid_rt  ON t3 (big_int_id, response_type)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table3_pkey ON t3 (big_int_id)


please take a look at the new tag i added and add the missing information

Please show tables and index definitions for all relevant tables. Please also share the EXPLAIN plan. We can't help you otherwise, there is no go-faster switch.

Get both execution plans and post them.

No no we need the plans for the queries above, not for a generic SELECT *. Also the definitions. What is the table r it doesn't seem to be anywhere? Your primary issue is probably a lack of indexing on the text column, but you could also improve by combining the two subqueries https://dbfiddle.uk/YtXFIlM2

@Charlieface sorry, I had some typos when I tried to anonymize the table names. I will upload the plans for the queries above shortly once I figure out how to do that

Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) ? That gives you all the details about the plan and the execution of the plan.

@FrankHeikens I couldn't get settings to work with postgresql. is analyze, verbose, buffers themselves fine?

Yes it is, and it already tells me you're working on an older version. What version exactly?

@FrankHeikens when I do SELECT version() it shows   PostgreSQL 11.22 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18), 64-bit but the psql i see that's used from my BIN has version 11.15.
will have the updated explain edited into the OP in a few

actually it'll take a bit longer. looks like using those new settings in explain requires the query to fully complete before outputting the plan

You are aware version 11 isn't supported anymore since November 9, 2023?

@FrankHeikens no I wasn't -- this piece of code is in a codebase that isn't maintained by me -- i'm just temporarily trying to make an edit to it for my needs. could the psql version here be a difference maker in the slowdown?

does using EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) add appreciable cost to the runtime?  the query has been running for 30min (previously it completed in about 15min-20min without the explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) iirc

actually it just errored out with ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout

@Charlieface "Your primary issue is probably a lack of indexing on the text column" according to the indexing information I edited into the OP, it seems it actually indexes on the text column and doesn't index on the original big_int_id column. so this can't be the reason right?

@jinkins: No, EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)  (or any other variant of EXPLAIN for that matter) cannot explain a slowdown of minutes for the same query. That points to intermittent or external factors like locking problems, contention for resources, or even hardware issues.

You have a mix of (unquoted) upper- and lower-case identifiers. Is there any significance to this?

You show the output of plain EXPLAIN. For performance questions, please show the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) if at all possible. That tells us so much more. Follow guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

@ErwinBrandstetter no significance to the case -- i just changed them all to lower case in the recent edit (they should have been all lower case). The "query plans" in the OP show the output of EXPLAIN. I can't seem to get EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to work on the modified query. it keeps giving me the error ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout after about 30minutes, it does work on the original query however

hmm the query is giving ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout without the EXPLAIN too. this wasn't happening earlier today

In a first step, I tidied up the query to become:
SELECT t1.id, t1.dt
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  t1.status IS NOT NULL
AND    t1.dt > now() - interval '15 minutes'   
AND   (
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.big_int_id = t1.big_int_id AND t2.count IS NOT NULL)
--                                       WHERE t2.text_id = t1.text_id
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM table2 t2 JOIN table3 t3 USING (another_id, big_int_id)
       AND t1.dt <= now()
      )

Most importantly, you can extract the filter t1.dt > now() - interval '15 minutes' from the OR-ed branch. This should make the plan simpler / the query a bit faster all by its own.
Also, there was a hidden corner-case issue in your original. BETWEEN includes lower (and upper) bound, while your other branch had the operator > for the lower bound. Typically, you want to avoid BETWEEN with timestamp values.
The raw comparing of text instead of bigint is typically slightly more expensive for two reasons: (1) text typically occupies more space. (2) text typically involves collation rules. And it smells like a design error to wrap integer numbers in text to begin with. But that's a side note. Not the main issue.
The main issue is the switch from Index Scan to Seq Scan on table t2. There is an index on t2(text_id), but it's not used, which can have many reasons. See:

Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan

Maybe it's already used with my modified query. Maybe it's just a matter of running:
ANALYZE t1;
ANALYZE t2;

Or:
REINDEX INDEX idx_t2_text_id;

Or:
VACUUM FULL t2;

The latter is invasive and blocks concurrent access for the duration. Maybe some non-blocking equivalent ...
Either way, all of that is boring maintenance. The more interesting detail is this:

98% of rows have text_id as null

Assuming t2.text_id is 98% null? While that percentage does not go down dramatically, a partial index is an interesting candidate (in addition or instead of the existing one):
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t2_text_id_notnull_idx ON t2 (text_id) WHERE text_id IS NOT NULL;

The much smaller index should be more readily used (and cheaper, too).
Maybe even more importantly, yet (it's hard to be sure building on incomplete info): Now that we extracted the filter on t1.dt, which looks selective (?!), an index on that might be a game changer:
CREATE INDEX t1_dt_idx ON t1 (dt);

May be refined one or the other way, depending on undisclosed infos.

"Assuming t2.text_id is 98% null? " yes, sorry, just clarified in my OP. t1.text_id is never null. With that said, I think we should ignore the 98% point. This table stores time series data, and the text_id was a new addition to the column that wasn't back filled. All future entries will populate that value

@jinkins: Your comment is even more confusing than the question. By "addition to the column", you mean addition to the row? Of which table? For the partial index on t2.text_id, the null percentage of t1.text_id barely matters ...
